# AppleScript - how to have actions ignore the tell statements they are nested within?

Tags: user-interface, applescript

I think that I am using `ignoring application responses` incorrectly.

What I'd like to do is to have nested actions which do not rely on being scripted by the applications they are nested within.

In the example below, there is a repeat loop that depends on `application "System Events"` and `application process myApp`, etc. But whatever actions that are within this loop, I'd like these to ignore `application "System Events"` and `application process myApp`, etc. How do I achieve this?

```
set myApp to "someApp"
set pPath to POSIX file "/Volumes/myDisk/outputPath"

tell application myApp to activate

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process myApp
        tell window myApp

            --some code here

            repeat while progress indicator 1 of sheet 1 exists
                ignoring application responses
                    set newPath to POSIX file pPath as alias
                    set currentDate to current date
                end ignoring
            end repeat

            --some code here

        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

The error that is returned:

```
get POSIX file (file "myDisk:outputPath:") of application process "somApp"
Result:
error "No result was returned from some part of this expression."
```

Here, I would've expected `get POSIX file (file "myDisk:outputPath:") of application process "somApp"` to just be `get POSIX file (file "myDisk:outputPath:")`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It all depends on who owns the command. Knowing who owns the command, you can redirect it to the correct application (or to the frameworks) with a nested tell sentence. For example, here I am trying to redirect the (current date) command to the frameworks of the **installed script additions**.

```
set myApp to "someApp"
set pPath to POSIX file "/Volumes/myDisk/outputPath"
set newPath to pPath as alias

tell application myApp to activate

tell application "System Events" to tell process myApp to tell window 1
    
    --some code here
    
    repeat while progress indicator 1 of sheet 1 exists
        tell scripting additions to set currentDate to current date
    end repeat
    
    --some code here
    
end tell
```

But that won't always help. The **correct and stable solution** is to "decouple" nested tell blocks and transform them into separate tell blocks. In your example, I would do it like this:

```
set myApp to "someApp"
set pPath to POSIX file "/Volumes/myDisk/outputPath"
set newPath to pPath as alias

tell application myApp to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell process myApp to tell window 1
    --some code here
end tell

set indicatorExists to true
repeat while indicatorExists
    tell application "System Events" to tell process myApp to tell window 1
        set indicatorExists to progress indicator 1 of sheet 1 exists
    end tell
    set currentDate to current date -- now this command is not nested
end repeat

tell application "System Events" to tell process myApp to tell window 1
    --some code here
end tell
```

Comment: Excellent, now I get it: redirect or separate blocks. In most case, separating works, but I've redirected for the loop depending on the tell block in question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`pPath` is already a `POSIX file`, remove `POSIX file`

```
set newPath to pPath as alias
```

---

In this case it's simpler with HFS paths

```
set hPath to "myDisk:outputPath"

...

set newPath to alias hPath
```

Comment: Yeah you're right, I think I mixed up a few problems there. But I can't find any resource on my issue. How do I ignore `tell application "System Events"` (and nested tells) when I have actions nested within these tell statements but unrelated to them?

Comment: You can use `tell me` or put the unrelated code in a separate handler.